Notification not showing Android 15
I am using the notifee library for react native with this code
const createTriggerNotification = async () => {
    await checkApplicationPermission();

    const date = new Date(Date.now());

    date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + 1);

    console.log(date.getTime());

    await createNotification(date);
  };

export const checkApplicationPermission = async () => {
  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    try 
    {
      await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.POST_NOTIFICATIONS,
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
};

const createTrigger  = (date : Date) =>
{
  const trigger: TimestampTrigger = {
    type: TriggerType.TIMESTAMP,
    timestamp: date.getTime(),
    alarmManager: {
      allowWhileIdle: true,
    },
  };

  return trigger
}

const createChannel = async () => {
  await notifee.createChannel({
  id: 'goc-channel',
  name: 'goc-channel',
  lights: false,
  vibration: true,
  badge: true,
  importance: AndroidImportance.HIGH,
})
};

export const createNotification = async (date : Date) => {
  console.log(date.toLocaleString())
  try
  {
    await createChannel();
    await notifee.createTriggerNotification(
      {
        title: 'Meeting with Jane',
        body: 'Today at 11:20am',
        android: {
          importance: AndroidImportance.HIGH,
          badgeIconType : AndroidBadgeIconType.SMALL,
          smallIcon: 'ic_notification',
          channelId: 'goc-channel',
          pressAction: {
            id: "default",
          },
        },
      },
      createTrigger(date),
    );
  }
  catch (e)
  {
      console.log(e)
  }
      

}

On devices with Android 13 and 14 the notification is It displays the correct time but with Android 15 it doesn't appear. It creates itself fine but nothing happens. Something I noticed is that on the first two devices the date appears like this
12/5/2024, 2:27:00 PM
6/12/2024, 10:23:09 AM
but with Android 15
6/12/2024, 01: 54:48
In all cases the timestamp is correct and verified
PD:
In Android 15 with this code, the notification is showing
 async function onDisplayNotification() {
    // Request permissions (required for iOS)
    await notifee.requestPermission()

// Create a channel (required for Android)
const channelId = await notifee.createChannel({
  id: 'default',
  name: 'Default Channel',
});

// Display a notification
await notifee.displayNotification({
  title: 'Notification Title',
  body: 'Main body content of the notification',
  android: {
    channelId,
    smallIcon: 'name-of-a-small-icon', // optional, defaults to 'ic_launcher'.
    // pressAction is needed if you want the notification to open the app when pressed
    pressAction: {
      id: 'default',
    },
  },
});

}
